# Invoking .Click event in Powershell

Tags: java, php, html, powershell

I'm trying to click on the login button for the page in the below file / url.

https://ufile.io/nryil

For some reason my code doesn't work. I've been messing with it for a day now. I'm kind of new to powershell so I'm not sure if this is something that's not capable, or if I'm missing something, but this is the latest code.

```
$username = username
$password = password
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("192.168.1.10/designs/imm/index.php")
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 10}
$secLink = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Continue to this website (not recommended).'}
$secLink.click()
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 10}
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 20}
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("user").value = $username
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value = $password
$link = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("Login").click
$link.click
```

I also just downloaded IMacros free trial to see how it's responding. I captured the below

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin_label"));
element.click();
element = driver.findElement(By.class("dijitOffScreen"));
element.click();
```

I even tried the below code after seeing that and still got nothing.

```
    $link = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('btnLogin_Label') | Where-Object {$_.class -eq 'dijitOffScreen'}
    $link.click
```

If I switch it to the below I get a "overload definitions void click()"

```
  $link = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('btnLogin_Label')
  $link.click
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing braces after your last click line. It should be `click()`, not `click`, I think

Comment: I've tried () in both scenarios on top.  One result is Exception from HRESULT 0x800A01B6.  The other is You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: I'd suggest to change your questions title to something indicating that you have problems invoking a link click, not logging in to a page

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Clijsters.  This is my first post so still getting use to it :).  i've looked through the suggested code, but not sure how to implement it into mine.  Any suggestions on that would be greatly appreciated.